# How to prevent MultipartFile to be automatically saved into local directory in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My application is writtent in Spring boot. I follow this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ to write an endpoint to upload image.

I was able to receive the image . All I want to do is to upload it to my own storage in another host and I also can do this. But I don't understand why the file is automatically saved in my project's directory. The directory will always contain images **(sample.png , sample1.png)** like this and it's not good on the production server.

The directory looks like this.

[image]

How can i prevent this?.

Comment: Open the spring boot reference documentation, hit ctrl-F, type "upload", click on the link in the TOC, read. Here's your answer: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration

Comment: it's not an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply copied the source code of the guide on Spring's website, then that's the expected behaviour since that's what the code in the guide does.

```
BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(Application.ROOT + "/" + name)));
FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
stream.close();
```

You need to pass a different path to `FileOutputStream` where the file will be written.